# Is Windows UAC's clicking OK authentication as secure as macOS/Linux's password authentication?

Tags: sudo, uac

Windows only show [Yes] or [No] for the same thing as Linux's sudo. macOS/Linux both require you to type the password. Is the password-less Windows implementation almost as secure as password-requiring macOS/Linux's impersonations? If so, why can't macOS/Linux do the same thing (requiring only clicking Yes for a user with sudo ability)?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That dialog only comes up when Windows has a weak UAC configuration.  With a strong UAC configuration it asks for a password as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have never seen UAC requiring password, unless the user is not in the administrators group, in which case I must enter the ID/password of a user in the administrators group. But even if it is true, that "weak configuration" is the default setting for any Windows version including those used in business environments. In that case, doesn't it mean that Microsoft is fairly sure that that method of just clicking Yes is secure enough?

Comment: No, the default weak configuration stems from the official Microsoft position that "UAC is not a security boundary"

Comment: Also probably the reason you haven't seen the more strict configuration is that it's a setting in "Local Security Policy" and not in the control panel.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-security-policy-settings#user-account-control-behavior-of-the-elevation-prompt-for-administrators-in-admin-approval-mode

Comment: @BenVoigt So, Windows does not have any special mechanism to prevent a malicious app from programmatically clicking "Yes" on the UAC dialogue?

Comment: It does, when using any of the configurations with "Prompt for (consent/credentials) on the Secure Desktop".  The problem is not with how the prompt handles input, the problem is that the default configuration doesn't reliably generate a prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UAC in "consent" mode (where it just asks yes/no) is *approximately* as secure as `sudo` against a malicious process running (or asking to run) on the same machine; you're (mostly) safe against the malicious process doing anything that requires admin privileges, unless you elevate the malicious process itself (which you could of course also do with `sudo`, e.g. if you run a Trojan installer). I say "approximately" and "mostly" because UAC does not separate low-privilege admins (members of the Administrators group but where UAC is removing actual admin rights) from full Admins (same user, but with their Administrators-group access membership usable, usually because UAC approval was given) as thoroughly as it separates actual users, and there have been UAC bypasses (allowing an unprivileged process to elevate itself) because of this, e.g. where a process manually checks what groups you're a member of and makes a corresponding access decision for you, rather than checking whether you have access to a particular resource directly. For the most part, though, it works.

UAC in the context of an untrusted *user* (for example, letting another person use your computer) is of course not going to present any barrier to malicious elevation of processes, assuming the account is a member of the Administrators group, and UAC is in consent mode. If the account isn't a member of Administrators, then - as noted in [Snaps-a-Lot's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/271761/53333) - the user will be presented with a very `sudo`-esque demand for credentials. Another option is to take UAC out of consent mode, though. Windows' Local Security Policy editor (`secpol.msc`) can be used to change UAC modes. Under "Local Policies" and then "Security Options", change the "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode" policy to "Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop", and log out and in again (or restart). This will make UAC behave much more like `sudo`; you will need to supply your password any time you want to elevate a process. This is obviously inconvenient, but it does mean you can let somebody else use your account without giving them admin access. ([Of course, you're still giving them access to everything *else*...](https://xkcd.com/1200/))

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.   Windows User Account Control (UAC) presents that dialog when your user is a member of the Administrators group.  If you click "Yes", you will elevate the process with the ability to modify anything on the system.  And if the requesting process were a malware application, the results could be disastrous.

On a secure computer, your process would be granted access only to the information and resources needed to complete the task at hand.  This is described as adhering to the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) (PoLP). Since macOS and Linux adhere to this, they is no need for something like UAC.  The following Super User post puts this in perspective for macOS:

[What does the sudo command do?](https://superuser.com/questions/185441/what-does-the-sudo-command-do)

The first step toward that on Windows is to remove users not solely dedicated to system administration from the local Administrators group.   With that measure taken, UAC would instead present a dialog is similar to macOS and Linux:

[image]

But how would you run an application with elevated privileges as needed without the Administrator having to credentials every time?   A macOS or Linux system administrator would have the option of granting you a PoLP adherent "[sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) privilege" to fulfill a similar request.  Windows does not include that facility, but Microsoft does provide the following guidance:

[Implementing Least-Privilege Administrative Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/implementing-least-privilege-administrative-models)

Privileged Access Management (PAM) tools can be used to fill this need for Windows, and to improve it on other platforms like macOS or Linux.   Gartner Peer Insights provides reviews and ratings of PAM software:

[Privileged Access Management (PAM) Tools Reviews and Ratings](https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/privileged-access-management)

If you have a smaller network, or if you simply want to emulate macOS/Linux sudo privilege delegation on Windows, there are some free, open-source alternatives you might consider:

- [**gsudo** from Gerardo Grignoli](https://gerardog.github.io/gsudo/)
- [**NSudo** from M2-Team](https://github.com/M2TeamArchived/NSudo)

Comment: @damn-vegetables, a BeyondTrust.com blog post,  https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/entry/what-is-least-privilege  , describes the basic securit thread posed by Windows lack of a Least-Privelege Administrative Model:   "In the case of Windows PCs, users often log in with administrative account privileges <which> massively increases the risk that malware or hackers may steal passwords or install malicious code delivered via web surfing or email attachments."